# Why is Windows Server 2003 addressing Directories and files like so --- C:\Directory\file\something.htm instead of C:/Directory/file/etc?

Tags: windows

The service that houses my server recently had to reprovision the server after a failure. The server is Windows and I'm running Apache to power a website.

Prior to the redo the directories and files were addressed with / as the following slash. Note the drive is partitioned and what used to be simple drive letters C, D, E are now C:\ , etc. How can this be changed?

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about, on Windows the directory separator has been backslash `\ ` since always (although, almost everywhere also the forward slash `/` is accepted seamlessly).

Comment: Still using Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 0):

Apache HTTPD should always do the directory-separator translation for you.  See this [httpd file system documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html)